# Non-invocable member 'HttpReqeust.Form' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am trying to get the value of input type=number from aspx file but Request.Form() is not working. it tell me that Request.Form() is not using like a method.  i am using the same way as i saw in ASP.net tutorials in W3school but it is getting the value of input.

Comment: Please add relevant [mcve] to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

Request Form is dictionary so you can get value this way

```
Request.Form["textBoxName"]
```